# Why do we need Optimal Substructure when proving the correctness of greedy algorithms

Tags: greedy-algorithms

According to Introduction to Algorithms, to show the correctness of a greedy algorithm, we need to show:

1. Greedy Choice Property (i.e. there exists one optimal solution that includes the greedy choice)
2. Optimal Substructure

Also, the book states: "Optimal substructure... is argu[ing] that an optimal solution to the subproblem, combined with the greedy choice already made, yields an optimal solution to the original problem."

The question I have is, why is Optimal Substructure itself not enough to prove that a greedy algorithm is correct?

More specifically, why can't I start with the "sub-solution" to the smallest subproblem, arguing it is optimal because base case, and then induction my way up until I show that the final solution is also optimal for the full problem?

Comment: How do you build this initial solution and prove that this will lead to an optimal solution? And how do you move up to solve the entire problem?

Comment: @Russel Instead of proving by showing that every step is optimal, I want to prove by showing the solution created by the greedy algorithm is optimal. Specifically, given a solution, it can be broken apart into smaller and smaller subproblems. The smallest problem A is the base case (e.g. an empty problem), so the solution to it is optimal. Then, I will move to the next subproblem B. By using the optimal substructure property, I show the greedy choice used at this step combined with the solution to A is the optimal solution to B. So on and so forth until I show the final solution is optimal.